# Podio authentication read permission

Tags: podio

I would like to use server-side flow to get read access to user's spaces.
Here is my login URL

```
https://podio.com/oauth/authorize?client_id=YOUR_APP_ID&redirect_uri=YOUR_URL&scope=space:read
```

But Podio asking me full permission.

I tried different options
https://developers.podio.com/authentication/scopes

Comment: Can you be more specific with which error are you receiving?

Comment: There is no error. I added scope=space:read in the login URL, but Podio asking me full permission.

Answer (score 1):

The scope argument is currently in Beta only and therefore not available for everybody. We still have some work to do on the granular authentication project before we are able to release it to public.