# Podio API Scopes not working

Tags: api, oauth, scope, podio

I have a similar problem as [Podio authentication read permisson](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/38143120/podio-authentication-read-permisson/39178690#39178690) but could not comment there so am posting a new question.

Whenever I redirect a user to Podio to grant us API access, podio does not seem to care about the `?scope=` argument.

Example url:

```
https://podio.com/oauth/authorize?scope=user:read&client_id=....&redirect_uri=..
```

see screenshot

[image]

Answer (score 3, accepted):

the scope argument is currently in Beta only and therefore not available for your clients. Could this be the issue?

We still have some work to do on the granular authentication project before we are able to release to public.

Would love your feedback in the beta space about how you are using the scopes as this will help us come closer to a public release!

Cheers, Sara - Podio

Comment: Hi Sara, thanks for the clarification. Perfect, I'm more than happy to assist in the development of this big improvement for the API. You'll hear from me soon enough ;)